# Scope of logs listed by CVS using rlog command

Tags: version-control, cvs, cvsnt

I haven't been able to find an answer for this.
If I run following command from command line

```
cvs -d :pserver:*User*:*Pass*@*HostName*:/cvsroot rlog -N -d "2008-08-01 00:00:00 < 2011-05-01 00:00:00" *Module*
```

What is the scope of the logs that are printed out? Does it contains logs only for the activities on the main trunk Or is it everything i.e. activities from all branches are also included?

NOTE: This might be a naive question, but I have not had enough experience with CVS and I need a quick and accurate answer, thus not much time to read up on things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Learned this hard way but, following command:

```
cvs -d :pserver:*User*:*Pass*@*HostName*:/cvsroot rlog -N -d "2008-08-01 00:00:00 < 2011-05-01 00:00:00" *Module*
```

actually lists all activities for that module. i.e. activities on trunk as well as all branches for this module.

To restrict the activity logs to a specific branch use:

```
cvs -d :pserver:*User*:*Pass*@*HostName*:/cvsroot rlog -N -d "2008-08-01 00:00:00 < 2011-05-01 00:00:00" -r*BranchName* *Module*
```

Note: there is no space between -r option and the branch name.

To restrict the activity logs to only main branch i.e. trunk use:

```
cvs -d :pserver:*User*:*Pass*@*HostName*:/cvsroot rlog -N -d "2008-08-01 00:00:00 < 2011-05-01 00:00:00" -r::HEAD *Module*
```